# .NET Remoting - How to do a callback to all connected clients?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, .net-remoting

I'm studying [.NET Remoting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting) and I see an example on [Remoting callbacks and events in .NET 2.0, A simple example](http://www.mctainsh.com/Articles/Csharp/RemoteCallback.aspx#A_simple_example). All works good.
Now my problem is if I try to start another client, the server doesn't callback to all clients connected to it but only to the last one.
How can I send callback to all clients?

Answer (score 1):

.NET Remoting is now superseded by [Windows Communication Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) (WCF), which is part of the .NET Framework 3.0. You should use WCF instead of Remoting.

Read [this](http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx) tutorial, on how to work with callbacks in WCF: